# Why is my UPDATE query with jsonb popping an error?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to update a row in my PostgreSQL database and it's saying it's not finding the x column. the thing is the column pg is trying to find is actually a parameter for the new value in the jsonb_set function, so I'm at my wits end.

It's hard to explain, so I included the query and the error it throws.

Tried adding quotes, double-quotes, brackets, inside and out... didn't work.

```sql
UPDATE public.sometable
SET somecolumn = jsonb_set(somecolumn, '{firstKey, secondKey}', someInputString), update_date=NOW(), update_username="someone@somewhere.com"
WHERE id=1
RETURNING *
```

I'm expecting the value of the row I'm updating to be returned, instead I get:

```
ERROR:  column "someInputString" does not exist
LINE 1: ...n = jsonb_set(somecolumn , '{firstKey, secondKey}', someInputString)...
```

Comment: `'someInputString'`

Comment: Are you sure? Because, as I stated, I tried with quotes, double-quotes, brackets, the quotes inside and outside the brackets.

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json

Comment: It seem like the issue is with someInputString.  Can you show us what someInputString is?  It does need single quotes around it if it's not a column reference.

Comment: klin was able to find a solution. Thank you guys also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deliver a valid json value as the third argument of the function:

```
UPDATE public.sometable
SET 
    somecolumn = jsonb_set(somecolumn, '{firstKey, secondKey}', '"someInputString"'), 
    update_date = now(), 
    update_username = 'someone@somewhere.com'
WHERE id = 1
RETURNING *
```

Note, I guess `update_username` is a text, so you should use single quotes for a simple text.

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=779174e583c46f472937feca40bef8ce)

Comment: Big thanks! And yeah, I should've put the single-quotes there, thanks again.